# common tracking work in wcf rest!

Tags: wcf, rest

i am working on wcf rest. i would like to do the following tracking work.

1. track the user **Real** ip address
2. track from where did the user came from ?i know i can use the referer header but since this is something very common task which most of the people do it would be better if some code is provided.in short i want to do the campaining work in this step.
3. i would be working on cookies , is there any library which can help me on the server side parsing the cookie field ?
   thanks

P.S i cannot enable AspNetCompatibilityRequirements.because my service is performance sensitive.

Comment: Are you asking where you should put code like this in a WCF service using WebHttpBinding, or are you asking how to get this information out of an HTTP request?

Comment: asking how to get this information out of an HTTP
header.

Answer (score 0):

For common tasks for all requests, I would look into custom [HTTP Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zec9k340%28VS.85%29.aspx).

> An HTTP module is an assembly that is
>   called on every request made to your
>   application. HTTP modules are called
>   as part of the ASP.NET request
>   pipeline and have access to life cycle
>   events throughout the request. HTTP
>   modules therefore give you the
>   opportunity to examine incoming
>   requests and take action based on the
>   request. They also give you the
>   opportunity to examine the outbound
>   response and modify it.
>
> ASP.NET HTTP modules are similar to
>   ISAPI filters in that they run for all
>   requests. However, they are written in
>   managed code and are fully integrated
>   with the life cycle of an ASP.NET
>   application.
>
> Typical uses for HTTP modules include:
>
> - Security. Because you can examine
>     incoming requests, your HTTP module
>     can perform custom authentication or
>     other security checks before the
>     requested page, XML Web service, or
>     handler is called.
> - Statistics and logging. Because HTTP
>     modules are called on every request,
>     you can gather request statistics and
>     logging information in a centralized
>     module, rather than in individual
>     pages.
> - Custom headers or footers. Because you
>     can modify the outbound response, you
>     can inject content such as custom
>     header information into every page or
>     XML Web service response.

Comment: as i said ,  i am on wcf rest with AspNetCompatibilityRequirements disabled because it causes performance issues.i was asking how can i access server variables (REMOTE_ADDR) without that option enabled .